# Laravel authenticate not redirecting to intended dashboard

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function username()
    {
            return 'name';
        }

    public function authenticated(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $request->name, 'password' => $request->password, 'userLevel' => 'Admin','status'=>'Active'])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('admin');
        }else if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $request->name, 'password' => $request->password, 'userLevel' => 'customer','status'=>'Active'])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('customer');
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is my laravel login controller and In this i want to redirect user based on their **user Level** to their **dashboard** but **intended redirect** is not working can anyone help e out with this i'm new to laravel so learning everything from scratch,

Comment: you dont call `attempt` again, the user is already authenticated and logged in before `authenticated` is called; in more modern versions that `authenticated` method takes a `$user` argument so you could check these conditions easily

Comment: @Amit Gusain check my answer. It will help to solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

authenticated function have two parameters request and logged-in user. so above problem we can solve like below.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($user->userLevel == 'Admin' && $user->status == 'Active') {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('admin');
        }else if ($user->userLevel == 'customer' && $user->status == 'Active') {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('customer');
        }
    }
```

Comment: still getting redirected to /home

Comment: @AmitGusain can you please give your related route code?

Comment: thank's for your help but now i resolved this by making manual authenticate instead of using laravel authenticated